# Raspberry Pi 2 SoC support in Linux 4.5

Tags: linux, kernel

Today Linux Kernel 4.5 was released with [*support for Broadcom BCM2836 (Raspberry Pi 2 SoC)*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1305eda751d7df3069b1fcb6f62036185acd24a0) (sic).

What does it mean exactly, given Raspberry Pi 2 is already working under linux?

Comment: It means that some support is in vanilla kernel. It doesn't mean that RPI2 hardware is fully supported in vanilla kernel. Raspbian uses kernel fork with almost complete RPI/RPI2/RPI3 hardware support.